# Translate datepickerfield to spanish

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

How can i translate the component **datepickerfield** in Sencha Touch to spanish or other languages?

I dont find it in the sencha touch 2 documentation. This is my actual code:

```
xtype: 'datepickerfield',
label: 'Date',
placeHolder: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translation to Spanish

Comment: It's a programming question, about how you can translate the component by code. Not about the translation itself.

Comment: I dont know the part of code that i have to change, i dont asking about transtale, im asking about the program works

Comment: You're right, the documentation for i18n of Extjs is sparse. This is what you can find in the official docs: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/guide/localization Did you read it already ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fairly certain Sencha Touch does not come with generated localization files, like ExtJS does. However Sencha Touch does come with an english template for you to translate and implement. Just load the relevant code (or part of it if that's all you need) before your app.

You can find the original file in src/locale, but here is a link to a fiddle showing all the locale override options:
**https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2bg**

If you need to change the order of the datepicker day/month/year, you can do that via the actual datepicker configuration (see *slotOrder* property in docs).

ExtJS takes the same approach, for the most part.